# Power BI - Cell should be coloured once I select it

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have created a table in Power BI and it has deal names, deal stage, amount, sales region etc.  Is there any way, where if I select the deal name - it should be coloured or highlighted and stay like that unless i remove it?

Comment: Do you have a slicer for selection? Can you post the input(dummy) and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it this way. Create an additional table with Label (column which you use to slice/select) don't add relationship!. For example, I want to highlight Day from the selected month (not filtering). We need to create a measure to check what is pickedup

```
WhatISelected = var __label = SELECTEDVALUE(MonthLabel[Calendar[Month]]])

return
if (SELECTEDVALUE(Query1[Calendar[Month]]]) = __label, 1,0)
```

Then go to conditional Formating:

[image]

[image]

Repeat for every column.

As you see below, I Select February.

[image]